# Update parent with null child collection without touching children

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities:

```
public class Box{
 private Long id;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "ID")
 public Long getId() {
    return id;
 }

 private Integer orderNumber;

 @Column(name = "ORDER_NO")
 public Integer getOrderNumber() {
    return orderNumber;
 }

 private Set<Cell> cells;

 @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = false, mappedBy = "dashboardBox", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JsonManagedReference
 public Set<DashboardCell> getCells() {
    return cells;
 }

}
```

This relation is bidrectional. For example I have box with id=3, orderNumber=5 and 4 Cells stored in database. During webservice I got box with id=3, orderNumber=7 and no cells - it's an use case. Now I would like to update only BOX, without deleting children. Is it possible and how? It's like I would like to update only level of entity without touching any children (associations) - even I have collection=null. In my case when I use `session.merge(box);` I delete cells, but I want to keep them..

Comment: You have `CascadeType.ALL`. You might want to read up on cascade options: https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: Ok, I understand now :) thank You